# How to change shape of dotplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data file with this basic structure:

```
Type Tm
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 3
B 3
C 1
C 1
C 2
```

I'm making a dotplot out of it using:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x = Tm,fill=Type)) +
geom_dotplot(binwidth=1,method="histodot",stackgroups=TRUE)
```

It works fine. However, I wondered if it's possible to change the shapes of the dots from the default circles. For example to make A triangles, B squares and leave C the default circles.
I tried various combinations of `scale_shape` but no success. Sometimes I get various error messages and sometimes nothing happens. This leads me to the conclusion that either I'm doing something wrong, or that it's not even possible. Which one is it?

**edit**

The comment by joran from Feb 2013 says that it hasn't been implemented yet. Were there any developments in this field in the past year and a half?

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/ggplot2/geom_dotplot$20shape/ggplot2/s0nv7G_P3jI/MVxswbalNw0J) from a few months back suggests that it simply hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it means brute Inkscaping it in the meanwhile.

Comment: [The ggplot2 issue tracker](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues?q=is%3Aissue+geom_dotplot+) makes it look like it's not on the radar. You could submit it as an issue so it at least shows up, but my guess is it won't be added unless someone from the community writes it.

Comment: I added it as an issue: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1111
+1 if you like it or comment away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is NO option for this, and it doesn't sound like there are any plans to make an option.

I'm frankly shocked.

https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1111

Perhaps Plotly has an option.

Answer (score -6):

I think that you just need to play with the pch parameter on your points.

```
#create A
x <- sample(1:10, 3, replace=TRUE)
y <- sample(1:10, 3, replace=TRUE)
A <- cbind(x,y)

#create B
x <- sample(1:10, 4, replace=TRUE)
y <- sample(1:10, 4, replace=TRUE)
B <- cbind(x,y)

plot(A, pch=11) # this will plot the points in A as stars of David
points(B, pch=14) # this will add the points in B as triangles inside squares
```

The best guidance I've seen on changing the shape/graphical parameters of points is here:
http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: The question was about `geom_dotplot` (http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_dotplot.html) in `ggplot2` which is different than a scatter plot. This answer uses base graphics.