# geom_dotplot: Change the shape and how do I put a line over the dotplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. I created a graphic with `geom_dotplot()` from `ggplot`, it worked
   fine. Now I wanted to change the shape of the points (to squares),
   this does not seem to be possible yet. Is there another way to
   create a stacked `dotplot` with squares?
2. I would like to draw a line over the `dotplot` to emphasize the
   shape. Is there such a possibility? (x is a continuous variable)

My code:

```
ggplot(sv15_e, aes(x = x, fill= factor(party_short), color = factor(party_short))) +
  geom_dotplot(stackgroups = TRUE, binpositions = "all", binwidth = 0.015)
```

How it looks:

[image: How it looks]

How it should look

[image: How it should look]

Comment: It seems that there's no option to change the shape of dotplot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099430/how-to-change-shape-of-dotplot

Comment: How about something like this from BBC: https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/73B7/production/_104232692_histogram-edited-nc.png ?